# How to make browsers to display image which is written to client in binary form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In ASP file, I read and output a image in binary form.

I want browsers to display the image, not download.

I have known that the header `Content-Disposition` should be `inline`.

But I can't determine what `Content-Type` should be used, because I can't make sure which format the image will be.

I know that `image/png` workes for png and jpg in chrome, but I am not sure whether `image/png` will be fit for all formats of image all the time.

```
'lngFileLength is the size of image
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", lngFileLength
Response.ContentType = "image/png"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline"
'rst1(strImageField).Value is the image in binary form
Response.BinaryWrite rst1(strImageField).Value
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I don't think my question is duplicate of [PHP : binary image data, checking the image type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273269/how-to-make-browsers-to-display-image-which-is-written-to-client-in-binary-form) ,because my question is "display image inside browser", not "check image type".

The best solution I wish is that we can tell browser to display, not download, image by setting header or other way.

Although "check image type" can solve this problem, it is the answer, not the question.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` according to the actual type of the image. You cannot just set it to an arbitrary type and expect it to work reliably.

To find the actual type of the image from the binary value stored in the database, you can load the value into a `System.Drawing.Image` object and then check the `ImageFormat`. You can use this function:

```
Function GetImageMimeType(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image)
    Select Case image.RawFormat
        Case System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
            Return "image/jpg"
        Case System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif
            Return "image/gif"
        Case System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
            Return "image/png"
    End Select
End Function
```

You can add other cases if you like.

You can also get the MIME type directly from the image like this:

```
Function GetImageMimeType(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image)
   'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo'
   For Each codec As ImageCodecInfo In ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
       If codec.FormatID = image.RawFormat.Guid Then
           Return codec.MimeType
       End If
   Next
   Return "image/unknown"
End Function
```

But this is a little less reliable and it won't work for images that were created on the fly, but will work for all images that were loaded from some source (file, stream, byte array, etc...).

If you don't want to load your binary into a `System.Drawing.Image` object, you can find the type of the image from the first few bytes. Here is a list of common type identifiers:

```
Dim bmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BM")
Dim gif = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GIF")
Dim png = New Byte() {137, 80, 78, 71}
Dim tiff = New Byte() {73, 73, 42}
Dim tiff2 = New Byte() {77, 77, 42}
Dim jpeg = New Byte() {255, 216, 255, 224}
Dim jpeg2 = New Byte() {255, 216, 255, 225}
```