# How do I call an image from a database of string type in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my code for displaying the image:

```
<asp:image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="AyoBelajar_Angka.aspx?id_bahan=7">
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString("id_bahan") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim strQuery As String = "select nama,kategori, gambar from ayobelajar where id_bahan=@id_bahan"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_bahan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value() = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Request.QueryString("id_bahan"))
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("gambar"), Byte())
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("kategori").ToString()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows(0)("nama").ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```

Comment: i can already save the data, but i have problem in display it

Answer (score 0):

Convert your byte array to base64String string and then assign it to your image control.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString("id_bahan") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim strQuery As String = "select nama,kategori, gambar from ayobelajar where id_bahan=@id_bahan"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_bahan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value() = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Request.QueryString("id_bahan"))
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("gambar"), Byte())
        'Converting Byte array to ToBase64String  
        Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        Image3.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," & base64String
 End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, can you help me , how make the image can display

Comment: I have saved the image data to the database in the form of strings, the image data that I save in the folder so that the database in the form of url link image. then I want to display the image just by calling the primary key

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your code-behind that your image was saved as a `byte` array not a string. Your code-behind that you posted does not return a string, it returns binary data and that cannot be placed in the `ImageUrl` property which expects a string.

You can convert the image binary data to a `Base64String` which you can then put in the `ImageUrl` property. It's pretty easy to do the conversion:

```
Dim ImageString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

However, you will have to prepend the string with the type of the image. If all your images are the same type, let's say jpg files, then that's easy:

```
ImageString = "data:image/jpg;base64," & ImageString
```

But if you have images of different types in the database, you'll have to detect the type of the image from the binary data. [Here is how you can do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284709/3215948). But it seems that you have the type in `dt.Rows(0)("kategori").ToString()`?

Finally, you need to return the string, so here is the complete code (change the jpg to whatever your images type is):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString("id_bahan") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim strQuery As String = "select nama,kategori, gambar from ayobelajar where id_bahan=@id_bahan"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_bahan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value() = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Request.QueryString("id_bahan"))
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("gambar"), Byte())
        Dim ImageString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        ImageString = "data:image/jpg;base64," & ImageString
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        Response.Write(ImageString)
        Response.End()
    Else
        'I don't know what code you have here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: on the else I do not add any code, and what I use to call the picture is correct

<asp:image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl ="AyoBelajar_Angka.aspx?id_bahan=7" 
                   Height="221px" Width="279px" />

Comment: OK, then my answer should work for you, assuming that the AyoBelajar_Angka.aspx page is different from the page that has the image. Have you tried it?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand, because i just studied it, can you help me, in order to display the picture, because i have tried some code and it did not go well

Comment: Just copy the code from my answer to your `Page_Load()` function and try it, it should work.

Comment: whether the code I made to call is correct

 <td>
                <asp:image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl ="AyoBelajar_Angka.aspx?id_bahan=@id_bahan" 
                   Height="221px" Width="279px" />
            </td>

Answer (score 0):

Hi tam you are have a imagepath in database right you want to display that image. you can convert it in ToBase64String format and display or it can be done directly. if your path is properly.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'From database get path and assign to imagePath variable 
    Dim imagePath As String = "~/Files/happy.jpg"
    Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath(imagePath)
    ' Will Convert filePath to bytes
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
    'bytes array to ToBase64String 
    Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
    'Attaching image to ToBase64String 
    Image3.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," & base64String
End Sub
```

> View

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
<p>Your app description page.</p>
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

> Output

[image]

> Folder view

[image]

Comment: I save the image file disebuah folder, but I want to call it with a database query

Comment: you  get path from database then assign it to  Dim imagePath As String variable that's it.